# MYSQL set default value of column to be new id

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

```
unique_id | master_id | othercolumns
```

If `unique_id` is a column with auto increment, is there a way to have the column master_id default value be the unique_id when inserting a new record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it "unique_id" and "master_id" are columns. No, you can't have one column default to the value of another, but you can create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) to set `master_id` to the value of `unique_id` on insert. Say the default for master_id is 0. Then the following trigger should work:

```
delimiter ;;

CREATE TRIGGER default_master_id
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
  IF NEW.master_id = 0 THEN
    SET NEW.master_id = last_insert_id()+1 ;
  END IF ;;

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into table ... set master_id=last_insert_id()+1;
```